/proc/pid exists but does pid not found in ps
I am seeing a very odd behavior.
/proc/1154/cmdline exists, and kill -0 1154 succeeds,
but ps -ef | grep 1154 and ls /proc | grep 1154 do not show anything.
1154 was a postgres process in the middle of shutdown (or the logs say but maybe they did not get flushed) when the vm was restarted.
How is this possible?

You are seeing a side effect of how Linux threads work.
A thread is a process (so it shows in /proc) but, by default, ps doesn't show threads.
You need to add -L to the flags to show the threads.
So ps -efL to see all the threads and your "hidden" process.

Kill -0 should not work though right?

Technically, threads don't show in /proc in that they won't be returned by readdir() there, but /proc/tid will resolve nonetheless.  They will show in /proc/pid/task/

@HariKrishnaS, on Linux, you can "kill" a thread, the signal will be delivered to the thread group (process) as a whole, not necessarily handled by that thread. See the section about CLONE_THREAD in clone(2) for details, and tgkill(2) for how to send a signal to a specific thread.

Thank you very much folks. This was indeed a thread!
